# iTunes Connect error "You backtracked too far. The application backtracking limit of 30 has been exceeded."

Tags: metadata, app-store-connect

Can anyone please explain what's the meaning of the error and is there a way to fix it on my machine? To me, it's happened when I was trying to save my updates to my app's metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I THINK its an AJAX error of some kind....maybe.

See this [link on apple's website](http://lists.apple.com/archives/webobjects-dev/2009/Dec/msg00101.html)
It may be what you're looking for.

How did you get this error anyway?

Comment: I was inside Safari, using iTunes Connect to update the info/metadata about my apps. Same as what we are doing here - using SO to post question and answers - there is nothing we do that is directly AJAX related.